# In rails is 'method:' parameter used only for delete action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, ruby-on-rails-5, action, destroy

I am new to Rails and came to know about the destroy action.When we write a destroy action for deleting something, in the link to delete it, we write the code:

```
method: :delete
```

So is the method parameter used only for delete, or is it used somewhere else too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default (Incase if you don't mention method type) it take `HTTP` method type as `GET`

So explicitly for any other `HTTP` request you need to mention `HTTP` method type for request.

Destroy action(which is use to delete some record) should be `delete` type `HTTP` request. so in link it need to mention `method: :delete` otherwise it serve request as `get`. hopefully this will clear your doubt.

References: -

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/routing.html#restful-routes

Comment: Thankyou. This answer really helped to clear my doubt

Comment: @Neha You can checkout the reference link given answer, feel free to upvote answer for future SO as well :)

Comment: Yes, Thankyou for the reference links.

Comment: @Neha Let me know for any further guidance as well